# Reload with setInterval stops reloading after a while

Tags: javascript, setinterval, addeventlistener, reload

I have a code similar to this (shortened it for brevity):

```
function reload() {
    location.reload();
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    foo();
    setInterval(reload, 20 * 1000);
})
```

This creates an indirect loop which works fine at first, but simply stops after a while.
I'm not a Javascript expert, would appreciate any explanation anyone can offer.
Thanks!

Comment: Try using `window.onload = () => {
    foo();
    setInterval(reload, 20 * 1000);
};`

Comment: @K.KDesgins Unfortunately it did not solve the issue, I wonder why this happens.